# How to write POSIXct with milliseconds using vroom_write()?

Tags: formatting, posixct, vroom

How can I write `POSIXct` columns with milliseconds using `vroom::vroom_write()`?

I can use `format()` before saving to "render" the time as character (see below), but I wonder if there's a neater way, e.g., by setting some option?

```r
# Example data
df = data.frame(time = Sys.time() + runif(5, 0, 10^6))

# Convert POSIXct cols
POSIXct_cols = sapply(df, \(x) "POSIXct" %in% class(x))
df[POSIXct_cols] = lapply(df[POSIXct_cols], \(x) format(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")))

# Save
vroom::vroom_write(df, "df.csv")
```